# How to loop 2 functions in python?

Tags: python, function, loops, crash

I have 2 functions that I need to call each other based on user settings. That is, if a user has repeat turned on it just needs to keep going until manually stopped, which I have a button for. How can I do this without causing an infinite loop error that crashes the program?

```
def T1_Timer(list):
    msg = list[0]
    global t1
    T1_List = list
    t1 = threading.Timer(MultiTimer2Settings.T1_Time, msg)
    while t1.is_alive():
        if not t1.is_alive():
            return
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
    Parent.SendTwitchMessage(msg)
    T1_List.pop(0)
    return T1_List

def DoRun1():
    T1_List1 = []
    T1_List2 = []
    while not StopPressed:
        T1_List1 = CheckList1(T1_List2)
        T1_List2 = T1_Timer(T1_List1)
    return
StopPressed = False
def StopButton():
    global StopPressed
    StopPressed = True
    return
def CheckList1(T1_List=[]):
    global t1
    t1 = threading.Timer(MultiTimer2Settings.T1_Time, "")
    if not t1.is_alive() and len(T1_List) <= 0:
        if MultiTimer2Settings.T1M1_Enabled:
            T1_List.append(MultiTimer2Settings.T1M1)
        if MultiTimer2Settings.T1M2_Enabled:
            T1_List.append(MultiTimer2Settings.T1M2)
        if MultiTimer2Settings.T1M3_Enabled:
            T1_List.append(MultiTimer2Settings.T1M3)
        if MultiTimer2Settings.T1M4_Enabled:
            T1_List.append(MultiTimer2Settings.T1M4)
        if MultiTimer2Settings.T1M5_Enabled:
            T1_List.append(MultiTimer2Settings.T1M5)
    return T1_List
```

Comment: Infinite loops don't cause crashes. Infinite recursion does.

Comment: Mutual recursion and use an ending condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `while` loop:

```
stopButtonPressed = False
var1 = <initial value>
while not stopButtonPressed:
    var2 = function1(var1)
    var1 = function2(var2)
```

Instead of each function calling the other, they should return the value that they would pass to the other function. You can then put these in variables and pass them in the successive calls.

Comment: the way you have it here you have 1 function calling the other 2 in succession but they need to pass vars back and forth so I'm not quite sure how to implement that.

Comment: Your functions don't return anything, so what do you need to pass?

Comment: @Elmseeker have you considered using a Queue to coordinate between your threads instead of calling one function from the other?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to pass the values.

Comment: @barmar The list is passed from CheckList1() to T1_Timer(), then after T1_Timer does what it does, it passes the remained of the list back to be checked if needs to be repopulated or not then it's passed back again...and so forth

Comment: And as shown in the answer, you can do that using return values instead of mutually-recursive function calls. That mutual recursion is the reason for your crash, because you hit the stack size limit.

Comment: @Barmar this is still crashing...Edited aboive to show current state...

Comment: Don't remove the original code from the question, future readers need to see what the answers are trying to fix. If you want to show the updated code, make it an addition marked with "EDIT".

Comment: `T1_Timer` has a `return` statement with no value after `if not t1.is_alive():`. `DoRun1` expects it always to return a value. If that's supposed to stop the loop, it need to check it and break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
Break = 0

Function1():
    test = 12
    print test
    return

Function1():
    test1 = 13
    print test2
    return

while Break < 15:
    Break += 1
    Function1()
    Function2()
```

calling another function using one function will not be in the loop therefore doing this is the simplest option

try running it!